# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created an ASP.NET Core MVC application to work with existing SQL Server database. I created needed models and database context using Scaffold. Then I wrote some code to fetch some data from the database table, but when I try to get it through app I get the following error in my console (I changed db name here):

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
> An error occurred using the connection to database 'dbname' on server 'localhost'.

and next

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'dbname.dbnameContext'.

I tried to manipulate with connection string, but I did not get any result. Tried to exclude `Trusted_Connection=true`. Hardcoded connection string into options, and checked for mistakes.

My `appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "FirstConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=True;",
    "SecondConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=dbname2;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // string conFirst = Configuration.GetConnectionString("FirstConnection");

    services.AddDbContext<IDatabaseContext, dbnameContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=True"));

    services.AddTransient<ISomeService, SomeService>();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Thanks!

PS: I tried to connect to database through VS SQL Server object explorer, and got connection string from properties of database which did not work either

Comment: Instead of Trusted Connection try using User Id and Password. `Server=localhost;Database=dbname2;User Id=your_user_name;Password=your_password;`

Comment: @honey_ramgarhia Unfortenately it didnt help

Comment: Can you post the ef code where you are trying to get the results from db

Comment: `public async Task<List<Member>> FetchMembers()  
{  
    var allMembers = await _db.Members.ToListAsync();
    return allMembers;
}`

Answer (score 0):

try use this syntax

```
 "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Comment: I tried, but no result. I am thinking that there might be problem in database.

Comment: this did not help I just tried and had the same problem. It is funny because it worked when I turned on my computer but not now so frustrating, I guess I must see what he did but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed the error.
Solution was that I had to enable TCP\IP listening in SQL server configuration.
The problem was not in connetion string. With those in my question all work fine.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Same problem, even worst, i run integrations test in my DataAccess package and the connection work fine, my CRUD methods impact into my BD. The problem appear when i run a GET or a POST in Postman to the server localhost:port/mycontroller, there it appear the same loging error than you dwerph, I dont understand what coud happend.